# Magento 2: Remove ReferenceBlock - Order Information

Tags: magento2, ui

How to find referenceBlock name? Been searching for internet about it but nothing better works aside from some referenceblock that already ask.

Got this problem, I need to move or remove this reference block, but cant find out what it was called. Please help, I’m new here.
[image]

In this pic, I need to remove the Order Information & Shipping method,
I browse and explore **vendor/Magento/Module-sales** and find the **xml** of the sale,order,view but the referenceblock name or block name is not working when I remove it in my default.xml

I successfully customize my Account Dashboard cause there was given referenceblock name in net. But for Order Information cant find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the path of a file.

> **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/info.phtml**

You can override in your theme or module and modify based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I see the info of the  Order Information, But what I see is their classes, What should I do if I want to use the <move element>, calling classes wont work on move element. Can you give me idea on how to move it? should I use css? not xml?

Comment: For sales order product information block name order_items and Sales billing/shipping/shipping method and payment method information block name sales.order.info. If you want to remove product information then

<referenceContainer name="order_items" remove="true" />

If you want to remove Sales billing/shipping/shipping method and payment method then 

<referenceContainer name="sales.order.info" remove="true" />

Or If you want to move a block then

<move element="order_items" destination="content" after="sales.order.info" />

You can use after and before based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove that container by using sales_order_view.xml in admin area. 
Create below xml file within any of your custom/third party module with below code:

> app/code/YourPackage/YourModule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_totals" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```